# Error: angular 11 WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, webpack, angular-cli

I am using ASP.NET Zero with Angular 11, this project was working fine, but after that I clone the angular project into another machine and there I have installed latest node version. It complies successfully in visual studio code but when we run it in browser it shows below error in console (see image):

WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE

[image]

If anyone have faced this in past or any suggestion to solve this issue, please provide answer as I have spent almost couple of days to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running npm install? You sure some functionality is not broken with a different version? Also can you be more specific on the versions of Node, npm and your webpack config etc.?

Comment: @LeroyMeijer
Yes, I have tried npm install and npm install --force both. but still facing same issue. Version details are node version : v16.15.1 and npm version : 8.11.0

Comment: It's always difficult (I find) to fix issues like this. I usually create a new project on the latest versions and use that configuration in my 'old' project and make it work like that! Keep in mind it could also be Angular 11 is not working with your versions of node/npm/webpack!